# -s: command not found in ubuntu 15.10

Tags: command-line, scripts, files, 15.10

I want to see if a file is empty or not, and I have seen that the command -s FILE. The problem is that when I try to use -s (both in the shell and in a script) I get an error saying: command not found. I have found the command on linux forums, so why isn't it available?

Comment: Could you please post an example of one such script/shell-command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-s` is not a command by itself, but an option for the `test` command, which can also be written as `[ condition ]`. Maybe you thought the brackets to be unnecessary, but they are not. The return value of `test` depends on the condition inside being true or false.

From the manpage test(1):

> -s FILE
>          FILE exists and has a size greater than zero

So you can use e.g. the following:

```
if [ -s "$file" ]; then
    echo "$file is not empty."
elif [ -e $file ]; do
    echo "$file is empty."
else
    echo "$file does not exist."
fi
```

Or something like this:

```
[ -s "$file" ] && echo "$file is not empty." || echo "$file is empty."
```

Comment: Ah, that's what I missed. Embarassing... Thank you : )